# php error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have written a very simple php script with the goal connect to mysql database, retrieve data and echo the data. The script is as follows:

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

// Prepare a select statement
$get_query = "select * from dishes";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($get_query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

//create array to put the table in
$response = array();
$response['dishes'] = array();

while($dishes = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    //create a temporary array
    $temp = array();

    //inserting the dishes in the temporary array
    $temp['unique_id'] = $dishes['unique_id'];
    $temp['title']=$dishes['title'];

    //push the temporary array inside response
    array_push($response['dishes'],$temp);
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

In the config file are necessary things to connect to my database. The table dishes is very simple, it has 2 columns, one for a unique_id and one with a title. The script is self explanatory as I supplemented comments in it. But if I run it, I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function        fetch_assoc() on boolean in ...

where the dots point to this file. I dont understand why this happens. Thank you!

Comment: `$stmt->get_result();` this is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

Answer (score -1):

Why using a While loop when u can use `fetch_all()`.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("select * from dishes");
if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $dishes = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all();
        $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: What does $this->conn mean?

Comment: This is your connection variable to the database $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);